# problems passing test with activeRecord, using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im testing a method, asking for a exact match, but the test is not passing? Any idea WhatAM I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

My Method:

```
 def self.search_by_number(number)
   return [] if number.blank?
   where("title LIKE ?", "%#{number}%")

 end
```

My spec:

```
  it 'returns an array of one video  for an exact match' do
      t1 = Video.create(title: 2345)
      t2 = Video.create(title: 2323)
      expect(Video.search_by_number(2345)).to eq([t1])
    end
```

I cant really find th problem here, this is the log-error im getting

```
1) Video search_by_number  returns an array of one video  for an exact match
     Failure/Error: expect(Video.search_by_number(2345)).to eq([t1])

       expected: [#<Video id: 3, title: 2345, description: nil, thumb_url: nil, large_url: nil, start_point: nil, start_time: nil, end_point: nil, end_time: nil, created_at: "2014-08-07 09:15:13", updated_at: "2014-08-07 09:15:13">]
            got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Video id: 1, title: 2345, description: nil, thumb_url: nil, large_url: nil, start_point: nil, start_time: nil, end_point: nil, end_time: nil, created_at: "2014-08-07 09:09:55", updated_at: "2014-08-07 09:09:55">, #<Video id: 3, title: 2345, description: nil, thumb_url: nil, large_url: nil, start_point: nil, start_time: nil, end_point: nil, end_time: nil, created_at: "2014-08-07 09:15:13", updated_at: "2014-08-07 09:15:13">]>
```

Comment: One is a `Video` object, the other is an `ActiveRecordRelation` which is why it fails.

Comment: @japed HI there! what shall I do to change this output?

Comment: if you're in rails 4, append `.to_a` at the end of the search. `expect(Video.search_by_number(2345).to_a).to eq([t1])`

Comment: @jvnill HI there! is this a new thing for Rails 4 cuz I've done this before? :)

Comment: @jvnill is not working either though

Comment: hmm no i don't think so.  your test is invalid, because `Video.search_by_number(...)` should return an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` but you're expecting it to return an array.  since you're expecting it to return an array, convert it to an array first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58865/discussion-between-yonigeek-and-jvnill).

Comment: @jvnill undefined method `to_a' for #<Video:0x007fcdd399bee0>

Comment: @jvnill many thanks to put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was that I need to install a database_cleaner. I've to point out that Im running Rails 4.1.1 and dat might also be the conflict, dont know.

My test database was not cleared after the test.

I had to make some changes inside the spec-folder!

Pls have a look at this link:

http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Once I did these changes everything was working well!

My code form the beginning was good though! ^_^)
Thanks for yr time though!